# Rails detect if session was created by SSO/SAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, single-sign-on, saml, onelogin

For my Ruby on Rails project, I have model `Account` and model `User`. `User` belongs to `account` and an `account` has many `users`.

For some accounts, I want to let users to use the regular Devise routes (i.e. routes controlled by controller devise/sessions). For some other accounts, I want to let users to use SAML/SSO to sign on.

I've implemented this successfully using gems `Devise` and `devise_saml_authenticatable`. Users in their accounts can sign in using either route depending on whether their accounts use SAML/SSO. I'm using Onelogin as my identity provider.

However, for logging out. I want users whose account do not use SAML/SSO to logout via

`destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/sign_out(.:format)                                devise/sessions#destroy`.

With this I can easily just put `=link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete`

On the other hand, I want users whose account do use SAML/SSO to logout via the SLO path of the identity provider. For one of such accounts, I've tried

`= link_to "Logout", 'https://mycompany.onelogin.com/trust/saml2/http-redirect/slo/xxxyyy'`

https://mycompany.onelogin.com/trust/saml2/http-redirect/slo/xxxyyy is the SLO link from Onelogin

Another aspect of my project is that users whose account do use SAML/SSO can also sign in using the regular devise sign-in routes. So it's their choice to use either SSO or devise routes to sign in.

If they signed in using devise routes, I want them to sign out via `destroy_user_session_path`. If they signed in using SSO, I want them to sign out via https://mycompany.onelogin.com/trust/saml2/http-redirect/slo/xxxyyy

Is there a way to detect if the current session was signed in using SAML/SSO so that I can do

```
if signed_in_with_sso
  = link_to 'Log out', https://mycompany.onelogin.com/trust/saml2/http-redirect/slo/xxxyyy
else
  = link_to 'Log out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete
```

I do not want to create a column in my users table to record whether they signed in via SAML/SSO or just devise each time they sign in. So no migrations, in other words.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a thought, but can you pop something into `session`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two potential options I see are either at the point of authentication, you set something in the session that indicates the authentication type. You can drive the authentication behaviour from that.

Or there is potential you could send a SAML request with isPassive=true to the IdP, which will return a SAML response if the user has a valid session with the IdP. You could then drive your logout behaviour from that response.